# Is it possible to reference an inserted column within the same INSERT?

Tags: postgresql, insert

This query gives the error:

```
create table qwe (a bigint, completed bit varying(100000));
CREATE TABLE

insert into qwe (a, completed) values (1000, repeat('0', a));
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably also saw the hint:

> HINT:  There is a column named "a" in table "qwe", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

You cannot reference a column value that does not exist, yet.

Instead, spell out the value again. Or use a subselect or CTE to provide `a` only once:

```
INSERT INTO qwe (a, completed)
VALUES (1000, repeat('0', 1000)::varbit);

INSERT INTO qwe (a, completed)
SELECT a, repeat('0', a)::varbit
FROM  (SELECT 1000) sub(a);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=05d049a8a94de40483edb02ac4429706)*

Also, you need an explicit cast to `varbit`.